# Dump Google Form Data To Different Google Sheets (Not Tabs) Based On Question Response

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm looking to have my Google Form put data into different Google Sheets (not different tabs) based on a question response.

For example, if someone selects 'Honda' for the car manufacturer, I want all the form data to dump into Sheet A.  If someone picks 'Toyota' I want all the form data to dump into Sheet B, and so on.  While these are separate Sheets, the tab names of the sheets match the manufacturer.

I'm familiar with Google App Scripts, but not an expert or developer by trade.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time for clients (if I'm correctly understanding what you're trying to do; your use of the words "sheet" and "tab" are still a bit unclear). Here is my recommendation.

1.) Send *all* form responses to a single spreadsheet. For the sake of this discussion, we'll say that this spreadsheet's name is `Master` (ex ID `1234567890abcdef...z`) and the name of the sheet within "Master" that is receiving the form responses is `All`. We'll further suppose that the car make is in `All!A:A` and that the full data runs `All!A:J`.

2.) Set up your individual sheets to pull from the `Master` spreadsheet's `All` sheet. For the sake of this discussion, we'll say that the first individual spreadsheet is named `Honda`, and the receiving data sheet within the `Honda` spreadsheet is named `List`. In `List!A1`, place a formula like this:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1234567890abcdef...z","All!A:J"), "Select * WHERE Col1 = 'Honda'",1))`

It will say "Loading..." and then a `#REF` error will appear. Hover your cursor over the error. A flyout will appear. Click the blue button granting remote access to the `Master` spreadsheet.

Your relevant data should fill in.

3.) Set up other individual sheets the same way, simply copying and pasting the above formula into `List!A1` of the new sheet and changing `Honda` within the formula to `Toyota`, etc.

**Note:**

I have read different places about instances of people saying that `IMPORTRANGE` calls have been dropping in and out sporadically. I myself have not experienced this problem with any of the systems I've built for people. But as a safeguard, I've seen other contributors across different forums recommending structuring the formula with an error-catching safeguard like this:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1234567890abcdef...z","All!A:J"), "Select * WHERE Col1 = 'Honda'",1),QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1234567890abcdef...z","All!A:j"), "Select * WHERE Col1 = 'Honda'",1)))`

(Notice the lowercase `j` in the `IFERROR`'s second parameter.)

Comment: That is how I have things setup currently and the issue is removing rows on the other sheets becomes cumbersome.  We then have to use a button script to select and move data up one row and then remove that row from the master sheet for the imported data range to get updated.  Ideally I want a Google Form script that will dump the data directly to a sheet without going to a 'master' sheet first.

Thinking out loud, I guess if it's possible to automatically copy the latest/most recent row to another sheet based on the manufacturer that would work too.  We just wouldn't touch the master sheet.

Comment: You (of course) know things about your setup and end goal that seem apparent to all, but which we "out here" don't know. After reading your post and your comment, I still have no idea why you would need to remove rows or "move data up one row and then remove from the master sheet..." Perhaps you should explain more within your post how you intend to use the sheets. With a clear understanding of the end goal(s) and usage(s), there is virtually no "problem" that can't be addressed or eliminated.

Comment: While we can't endorse any platform over another here, there are great forms platforms that allow branching/funneling based on conditions (i.e., sending x-type data to spreadsheet-a, y-type data to spreadsheet-b, etc.). I suggest you look into those options. However, again, it's difficult to imagine what problems that would solve that other methods couldn't using the Master-Child setup.

Comment: Hey Erik, We have sheets that need to be kept tidy as we have 3rd party people fix some hardware for us and when they are done, the row get copied to a 'completed' tab (for historical data, etc) and we remove row for that hardware so we have know what currently in the queue to get worked on.

Comment: All of that kind of filtering based on status can be accomplished either from the Master sheet or from within each child sheet. However, I think they kind of analysis, setup and specific recommendations you require likely go beyond what can be offered via a free, volunteer-run forum (i.e., you may need to hire someone). There are experts who donate our time here as we're able, but the forums are really designed to offer a "nudge in the right direction" to many, many people, as opposed to being a place where anyone could get expert, customized, time-intensive work or consultation done.